# Should the route handlers use containers or presentational components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

For example:

When starting my app I created a connected component which contains some callbacks to dispatch actions, and renders a single presentational components which in turn contains many other presentationals that make up the "screen" (or "scene").

But then I realised that many of those components were having unnecessary rendering, because each of them requires a different part of the state.

So, what would be the the solution? maybe pass to the route handler a single presentational that renders many containers, and each of them connects to the state it cares about? then,  What if two components use the same part of the state, should they be different containers nevertheless?
And, if I go with this approach, would it make sense to have a folder 'views' to store those route handlers?

How have you dealt with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what "unnecessary rendering" means? Could you provide some code examples highlighting the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: @CalvinBelden This container was connected to a large part of the state, but not every component needed all of it. as a result, many components got re-rendered when a part of the state changed, although they weren't concerned with the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `shouldComponentUpdate()` on those components and it won’t be as much of an issue. See [Advanced Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) and [A Deep Dive into React Perf Debugging](http://benchling.engineering/deep-dive-react-perf-debugging/) for details. This is exactly what components generated by `connect()` do with React Redux.

That said feel free to `connect()` components below. There is absolutely no obligation to `connect()` route handlers and leave the components below presentational. I would suggest to start with presentational components, and wrap some of them in `connect()` when they become tricky to work with and require passing too many props down.

Comment: ShoukdConponentUpdate is a great idea. regarding the second paragraph, you are suggesting to start passing the router a connected container that renders many presentationals. Then, if the need arises, connect those, so if all of them end connected, the route handler component would become a presentational that renders many containers. Correct?

Comment: @Emilios1995 Pretty much. You can also nest containers when it is convenient. See lessons 20 to 23 from my [free Egghead course](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux).